# I cannot insert link from image location into database

Tags: php, laravel, validation

i want to insert `ads (name, title, last, image)`, for image i want to insert location link in database, but when i go to image field i find `D: \ wamp \ tmp \ phpB40B.tmp`, and when I try `dd ($ request-> image)` it gives me field is correct `"profiles \ October2020 \ eyJpdiI.jpeg"`, and when I try `dd ($ request-> all)` it displays `D : \ wamp \ tmp \ phpB40B.tmp` for the image.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $jdate = Carbon::now();
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $imagee = Crypt::encryptString($image);
        $image->storeAs("public\profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year,$imagee.'.'.$image->extension());
        $request->image = "profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\\".$imagee.'.'.$image->extension(); 
        }
        dd($request->image);
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'category_id'=> ['bail','required'],
         'titre'      => ['bail','exclude_unless:category_id,1','required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
         'name'       => ['bail','exclude_unless:category_id,2','required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
         'last'       => ['bail','exclude_unless:category_id,1','required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:255'],
         'image'      => ['bail','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','exclude_unless:category_id,1','required','max:2048'],
         ]);
        File::create($validator->validated());
        return Redirect::to("/")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

Comment: "public\\profiles\\"  why did you escape backslash? and also what is error message you get

Comment: @Jerson This code ` $image->storeAs("public\profiles...` is to put the image in a storage folder and the other code `$request->image = "profiles\\".$jdate->forma...` for insert link of image in db, i dont get any error ,but i cant insert link of the image location it is to insert  D : \ wamp \ tmp \ phpB40B.tmp